# How to create combobox with django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create something like a combo box with django model, but i don't find any field type to do that.
something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTf4V.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can do this in **models.py:**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    select_gender = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=select_gender)
```

In **forms.py** file, do this:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'student_name'  :   forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'student_gender'  :   forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }
```

This is the way you can do.